# display single row by id - spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, web, model-view-controller

so i want to display single row by its id on spring mvc

i have this dao:

```
public Message getMessageById(int id){  
    String sql="select * from tb_message where id_message=?;";  
    return template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{id},new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Message>(Message.class));  
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/replymessageto/{id}")  
public String viewforreply(@PathVariable int id, Model m){  
    Pesan currentmessage=dao_send_message.getMessageById(id);  
    m.addAttribute("command", currentmessage);
    return "viewcurrentmessage";  
}
```

i can display the value if i use this on my jsp:

```
<form:form>
   <form:input type="text" path="message_title" name="message_title" class="form-control"/>
</form:form>
```

but what i want is to show the value only on `<p></p>` tag

Comment: You might look for place holders and replace that with the value u got from your API.

Comment: @AshutoshSharma thanks for replying... but i dont understand by what you mean. can you explain it more? thankyou

Comment: Learn the JSTL and the JSP EL. It's the standard set of tags to do basic things like displaying data, doing tests, loops, etc. The Spring form tag library is used for... forms. All you need is `<p><c:out value="${command.message_title}"/></p>`. And please, respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @JBNizet it works! thankyou so much!!! actually ive already tried `<p><c:out value=""/></p>` before. but instead of putting `command` i put `currentmessage`... again thankyou so much!!!